# The service instance cannot be created because paid service plans are not allowed

Tags: ibm-cloud, dedicated

I would like to use the dedicated bluemix for a streaming analytics POC.  When I try to create the service I get this message.

The service instance cannot be created because paid service plans are not allowed.

What can I do to address.

Thanks,

j

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a Bluemix free trial account.

With a free account you are limited to create services that offer a free plan only. 
If you are trying to create a service from a paid plan you need to upgrade your account to a paid account.

You can see different types of accounts in the link below:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/pricing/index.html#pricing